# Django model: store reference to unknown class

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to store ForeignKey reference to the undefined (yet) class? I couldn't even google it, since I dont know what the technical terminology use to describe it :/

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
 name=models.CharField(max_Length=100)

class Car(models.Model):
 name=models.CharField(max_Length=100)

class CartItem(models.Model):
 item_type=models.ForeignKey( **<I dont know yet, maybe Book, maybe Car>** )
 ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the [`contenttypes` framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/), or possibly even [generic foreign keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations), depending on how you want to store the data. Using content types, you can do something like this:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    item_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
```

Comment: I wish I had reputation points. Thank you for showing me the way.

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me with next step where I landed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982003/retrieve-contenttype-genericforeignkey-object-in-manytomany-relationship of course if you wish :)